# Upgrade Application Authentication to Core 2.0+

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We are switching form .NET 4x to .NET Core and now I have problem with the authentication.

The main problem is, that the authentication is in an assembly and I am pretty new to Core, but read into it. There are some problems occuring, for example IPrincipal.

So I created my middleware and registered it in the StartUp.cs. After that I am Invoking it to start the authentication process.

In .NET i used this:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NameValueCollection header = new NameValueCollection();
            header.Add(Request.Headers);
            IPrincipal princ = new CompanyPortalPrincipal(header);

            Context.User = princ;
            CompanyPortalPrincipal pp = Context.User as CompanyPortalPrincipal;
...
```

In Core I cannot use this.

First of all my MW:

```
private void BeginInvoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            NameValueCollection header = new NameValueCollection();
            header.Add(context.Request.Headers);

            IPrincipal principal = new CompanyPortalPrincipal(header);
            context.User = principal;
...
```

The first problem is in `header.Add(context.Request.Headers);` because it says that it cannot convert from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary` to `Collection.Specialized.NameValueCollection`.

The second problem is that in Core you use something like `ClaimsPrincipal`? Which I cannot use, because I am not allowed to touch the CompanyPortalPrincipal and this is using IPrincipal. Thus I cannot do `context.User` because in short it cannot convert from `IPrincipal` to `ClaimsPrincipal`

Answer (score 1):

> The first problem is in header.Add(context.Request.Headers); because it says that it cannot convert from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary to Collection.Specialized.NameValueCollection.

ASP.NET Core now uses the `IHeaderDictionary` to store headers. You could convert `IHeaderDictionary` to a `NameValueCollection` in following way:

```
NameValueCollection header = ctx.Request.Headers
    .SelectMany( kvp => kvp.Value, (kvp, value) => (kvp.Key,value))
    .Aggregate( new NameValueCollection(), (seed, current) =>{
        seed.Add(current.Key,current.value);
        return seed;
    });

// now you get the header
IPrincipal principal = new CompanyPortalPrincipal(header);
```

> The second problem is that in Core you use something like ClaimsPrincipal? Which I cannot use, because I am not allowed to touch the CompanyPortalPrincipal and this is using IPrincipal. Thus I cannot do context.User because in short it cannot convert from IPrincipal to ClaimsPrincipal

Not sure how your `CompanyPortalPrincipal` is defined. But the [`ClaimsPrincipal` constructor](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Security.Claims/src/System/Security/Claims/ClaimsPrincipal.cs#L107) accepts a parameter of `IIdentity`, so you could create a new `ClaimsPrincipal` as below:

```
var userPrincipal =  new ClaimsPrincipal(principal.Identity);
// if you have multiple identity, invoke :
// ... userPrincipal.AddIdentity(...)
context.User = principal;
```

There's no magic in the `ClaimsPrincipal`( [source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Security.Claims/src/System/Security/Claims/ClaimsPrincipal.cs)) or `ClaimsIdentity`([source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a6f76f4f620cbe74821c6445af3f13e048361658/src/System.Security.Claims/src/System/Security/Claims/ClaimsIdentity.cs)) . You could modify the principal as you like,for example, add claim add identities.

Comment: You mean `context.User = userPrincipal` or? After that I have define it like this `CompanyPortalPrincipal cpp = context.User as CompanyPortalPrincipal` which throws the error that it cannot convert `System.Sec.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` to `Company.CompanySystem.Sec.Principal.CompanyPortalPrincipal`

Comment: @SpedoDeLaRossa Sorry, it should be `context.User = userPrincipal`. Because `context.User` is a `ClaimsPrincipal`. By the way, why do you create another principal by `CompanyPortalPrincipal cpp = context.User as CompanyPortalPrincipal`?

Comment: @SpedoDeLaRossa  I'm asking this because I see your original code `IPrincipal principal = new CompanyPortalPrincipal(header); `. That means you've already created a principal of `CompanyPortalPrincipal`